# Unable to work with the static IP with my blackberry project

Tags: blackberry

I have done a project where the mobile sends it's **latitude and longitude to the server** every 15mins. To connect with the server every time i used to enter the **IP address** of the server **dynamically** in my application. Whenever i tick an option in my app mobile sends an notification to the server with the details of the option that i checked(Check Box) and everything is working fine. I used the code like below:

```
String url="http://"+ipaddr+"/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid="+empid+"&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+";interface=wifi";
```

Now i got a new Internet connection with **static IP**. And now i **unable to send** the notification to the server. When i am checking a checkbox it is displaying nothing either in the server or client. I tried using deviceside=true; deviceside=false but all my attempts are in vain. What is the problem here? Please kindly help me

Comment: Are you on simulator or real device? If on real device what do you mean under "i got a new Internet connection with static IP"?

Comment: i am testing on my mobile 8520

Comment: Hm.. I'm trying to figure out how this is possible. Is there any wireless providers who offer internet with static IP? Or maybe you're talking about WiFi connection via your home WiFi-router?

Comment: Guys, when downvoting please also state a reason, this way we can learn something from our mistakes, otherwise it just smells like a bad game.

Comment: BSNL in India provides static IP connection. And i am not using wifi router for my application to work on. Before i used to work with wifi but later i need to deploy my app in other city and server in my location. So, now i don't want to use wifi and here started the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the apn. We should include **;deviceside=true;apn=airtelgprs.com** in the url is the first option or go to Options -> advanced Options -> TCP/IP -> check the option APN Settings Enabled and give APN: airtelgprs.com. It works fine